# Where can a UK resident get a Maestro card?

Tags: uk, payment-cards

Looking for an issuer of Maestro cards in the UK, as I will be travelling to and from and The Netherlands frequently, and do not wish to carry cash and will not be becoming a resident.

Mastercard and Visa are not widely accepted there and I have been caught out because of it before.

Even though Mastercard own Maestro, they do not issue Maestro cards in the UK - does anyone know where I could get a Maestro card, preferably for a low fee? Bunq bank offer a Maestro for a monthly fee but I'd rather find a more mainstream bank if possible.

Comment: This question might be better on https://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Not an answer, but my understanding is that V Pay (the Visa branding for EC cards) will also work wherever Maestro cards do. This might help in your search.

Comment: I would challenge the assertion that "Mastercard and Visa are not widely accepted [in the Netherlands]".  I lived there for 4 years had had no problems using my UK issued VISA credit card and my UK issued VISA debit card, in ATMs, and at a variety of POS devices in stores, restaurants, and petrol stations.  Once I got an account at AbnAmro in the Netherlands, I used the cards they issued, again a VISA credit card and an AbnAmro bank ATM card (VISA as well, I think), in many locations in the Netherlands, UK, and other countries too.

Comment: @Nick depends utterly on where in the country you are and the nature of the store. Away from the major tourist areas credit card reception is very limited, except at petrol stations and larger restaurants. It's simply not economically viable for stores that get 1-2 credit card transactions per week to pay the fees.

Comment: I lived in NL for 11 years, but have left now. I still have an ABN account as I travel there regularly. Since a few months ago, they have raised their monthly charge for a non resident account from 2 to 8 Euros a month. This means that I am currently paying euro 12.95/month just to hold the account. I think this is outrageous so am also looking for a Maestro card (or VPAY) pre-paid or otherwise, that I can have for free. The comments on NL about the need for Maestro are true. Non Maestro/EC cards can only be used in mainstream stores/Petrol stations and hotels that regularly service tourists.

Comment: @Mike You may have to hurry up as Mastercard are retiring Maestro. https://payneteasy.com/blog/maestro-is-retiring-debit-mastercard-takes-over . I'm not sure how thats going to work where Maestro is accepted by Mastercard is not.

Answer (score 6):

None of the banks above issue a Maestro Card. The only banks active in the UK who DO issue Maestro cards are a company called Quidity, a company called Splash, and Revolut. And Revolut will only issue you with a Maestro Card if you live in Germany, Austria or the Netherlands! The Quidity card is expensive. £5 for the card, £5 "membership fee" for a year, a 3% transaction fee for every payment, 3% top Up Fee using Paypoint, or for a Credit/Debit Card 2% (subject to £1.00 minimum fee). Oh, and £1.50 ATM withdrawal (+ additional 2% for charges over £50). Still want one ?

http://www.quiditycard.com/help02.html

Or there's Splash.

http://www.splashplastic.com/about.html

Same membership and card issuing fees, a mere 2.5% transaction fees, 3% top up Fee using Paypoint, or for a Credit/Debit Card 2.5% (subject to £1.00 minimum fee), and £1.50 per ATM withdrawal.

Maestro cards are widely accepted in the Netherlands, Visa and Mastercard less so. Indeed, there are branches of Albert Heijn that will ONLY accept Maestro - no cash, no other cards.

Comment: The other solution are bad enough for Splash to merit a mention but are you affiliated with them? “a mere 2.5% transaction fees” reads like advertising copy.

Comment: No, I was being entirely sarcastic, sorry if that wasn't clear. 2.5% transaction fees are outrageous, never mind 3%.

Comment: Could OP change their address to a Dutch one (their hotel or Airbnb should work), then get a Maestro card from Revolut?

Comment: @JonathanReez if he did that he could get a Dutch bank account with a Dutch card and just transfer some funds into that. Probably cheaper.

Answer (score 4):

Not strictly an answer to your question, but good to know: next to Maestro all shops in the Netherlands also accept VPAY cards (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_Pay). So if you cannot find a bank in the UK that offers Maestro, maybe you can find one that offers VPAY.

Answer (score 2):

Bunq's free account does not come with a card, but you can still use their app to make mobile contactless payments.

You might be able to open an account with a mainstream Dutch bank as a non-resident, but it seems from bank websites that they'll all require you to have some sort of connection to the Netherlands, or otherwise have a BSN (citizen service number). You could consider registering in the Netherlands as a non-resident to obtain one of these - there don't seem to be any requirements for who can do so!

Answer (score -1):

## Get a prepaid card

You should be able to find a prepaid MasterCard card in shops in Netherlands. You can probably top them up using a Visa. Pre paid Maestro cards seem impossible to find.

Comment: that won't help, because MasterCard cards are (mostly) not accepted in shops in the Netherlands